# Android - unable to open URL in the browser

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, action

I'm attempting to open a link in external browser so in my activity I have this code:

```
// usual SSL URL such as https://foo.com but very long since it contains OAuth params
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url); 
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

It works as intended but once in a while I get this error. Any idea why and how to handle it?

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent 
        { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://api.foo.com }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2836)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2942)
at foo.activity.LoginActivity$2.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:128)
at foo.activity.LoginActivity$2.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you be any more specific about the "once in a while" part? IOW, is it "once in a while" for the same device without any changes, or "once in a while" in that you get this error from some random user? If the latter, are there any patterns in terms of device?

Comment: Sure. The app is live with 60K+ active (very active) users. And I've seen this error in my logs 2 maybe 3 times in past 2 weeks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd handle it by catching the exception and telling the user to get a real Android device. :-)

Seriously, `https` is part of the [Browser app](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Browser.git;a=blob;f=AndroidManifest.xml;h=dc8f599034224eec5d4d9674c58c55afa23a9f8f;hb=HEAD). The only way I can see where this exception would occur would be if somebody is running a modded ROM or some screwball Android device where they messed up the browser's manifest file.

You could also use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to determine in advance that the `startActivity()` call would fail, in which case you could...ummm...do something...

BTW, I am assuming that your URL is consistent. If your URL varies, then the problem may be with the particular server you're hitting on occasion. If it is issuing a redirect to an HTTPS URL that is not one of the standard browser MIME types, then I can see this error occurring. In that case, you might consider logging the URLs that are giving you grief and see if you see a pattern there.

Comment: This was indeed just one user so far (though he did fail multiple times). Droid Pro with a fingerprint of (verizon/venus2_vzw/cdma_venus2/venus2:2.2/V2_2.26.2/2.26.2:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys)

Comment: URL is consistent. It's location of OAuth login page + required parameters

Comment: @DroidIn.net: If you have not done so already, you could try asking on the MOTODEV forums. But, if you think that you have other Droid Pro users working successfully, I'll bet it's something unusual with his device, such as a modded ROM.